# Which herb provides the highest chance to mill Misty Pigment?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Misty Pigment is a reagent gained from milling the new herbs added in Mists of Pandaria required to make Starlight Ink, which is used in high level inscription for the creation of Scroll of Wisdoms and Darkmoon Cards, amongst other things.

Each of these herbs has a chance to mill down into Misty Pigment, in addition to the usual Shadow Pigment. Which herb provides the highest chance to mill Misty Pigment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From milling *thousands* of Cataclysm herbs, I have discovered that Whiptail returns twice as much rare pigment as Cinderbloom.

Specifically, 100 mills will return (on average)

```
Herb              RarePigments CommonPigments
Low Quality (CB)  25           250
High Quality (WT) 50           300
```

[image: Cata Herb Comparison]

Similarly in Mists of Pandaria, `Fool's Cap` (the only high quality herb) gives twice as much rare pigment as the other MoP herbs.

Unfortunately, due to the high cost of Fool's Cap on my server, I have only milled it 16 times, which is not good enough to show the difference.  If you have Fool's Cap and want Misty Pigment, you'll get more Pigment if you sell the Fool's Cap and buy any other MoP herb that costs less than half the Fool's Cap.  However, you will have to mill twice as many times - if you are time limited instead of gold limited, mill the Fool's Cap.

Comment: Aside: some people say "there's a 25% chance of rare pigment coming from low quality herbs", but that is inaccurate. The chance of rare pigments occuring is lower than 25%, but you can get up to 3, making the average yield 1/4 pigment per mill.  While 1 stack is expected to yield 1 pigment, one stack frequently yields 0, and can theoretically yield 12.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wowhead database, Fool's cap give you the highest chance to mill Misty Pigment.
You can check by yourself here : http://www.wowhead.com/item=79253/misty-pigment

Comment: This answer is not a full answer.  WowHead is based on user data submitted to WowHead.  This means of the data being submitted Misty Pigment was generated by milling Fool's Cap the most.  In reality all of the herbs at the same level would result in a near equal chance for Misty Pigment.

Comment: I think you might have a point, I checked the data for Icy Pigment (the cata equivalent to Misty Pigment http://www.wowhead.com/item=43109) and since the database is much larger, it might be accurate. All high level herbs had the same ratio, we will surely see the same figures in MoP when enough data has been collected.

Comment: Looking at IcyPigment shows 50% for Adder's Tongue, Icethorn, and Lichbloom... 25% for the rest - validating your answer.  +1